# Database Design without NULL values and Repeating Data for iOS App

Tags: ios, database-design, persistence

Having figured out most of my data-model for a new iOS app, I'm now stuck with a problem that I've been thinking about for a while.

An 'Experiment' has a name, description and owner. It also has one 'Action' and one 'Event'.

An 'Event' could be different things: Time, Location or Speed.

Depending on what the 'Event' is, it can have a different 'Type'. For example, Time could be one-off, interval, date-range, repeating or random. Location could be area or exact location.

Each 'Type' then has a value that has a data type unique to itself. The Time One-Off could be a date value of 12:15pm and the Location Exact could be a GeoPoint value of (30.0, -20.0).

**The Problem**

- How do I design the data model so that the database is not riddled
  with NULL values?
- How do I design the data model to be extensible if I add more 'Events'
  and 'Types'.

**Thoughts**

As an Experiment only has one Action and one Event, it would be wrong to separate these two into different tables, however not doing so would cause the Experiment table to be full of NULL values, as I'd have to have columns for Event, Event Type and Event Type Value to compensate for all of the possible data types one could enter for an Event Type Value. (date, int, string, geopoint, etc)

Separating the Event and Event Type into a separate table would probably fix the NULL value issue however I'd be left with repeating data, especially in the case of time as the Event with Type One-Off as 12:00pm, as this would exist in other experiments, not just one. (Unless I create EVERY possibility and populate a separate table with these - how could I easily do this though?)

Maybe I'm over complicating things, maybe I'm missing something so simple that I'm going to kick myself when I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think about your data model in terms of objects not tables. Core data works with object graphs so everything in core data is an object. In Objective-c you work with objects. This is why you don't need a ORM tool. If you think in terms of objects then I think the model below (obviously needs work but you should get the point) makes sense. The advantage of separating your concepts out into objects like this is that you can look at your problem from multiple angles. In other words you can look at it from the Experiment angle or from the Event angle. I suspect you will want to do something with the data such as use your Time object in your code to show on a calendar or set a reminder. Fetch all the events for all experiments of a specific type, etc. By encapsulating these data items in objects in core data, everything is ready for you to leverage, manipulate and modify in your code. It also removes the null value issue you identified. Because you won't be creating objects for null values, only for values that are relevant to your experiment. That being said, you might want to break down the model even further depending upon the specifics of your program. Also, you would not have the repeating data issue you mention if you design this properly. Again, you're not dealing with rows in a table you are dealing with objects. If you create an Event Type object with "one-off 12:00pm", you can assign that Event Type objec,t through its relationship, to as many Event(s) as you wish. You don't create the object again, you simply reference it. When you think of the relationships think "X can be associated with Y". For example, "An Experiment can be associated with only 1 Event", "An Event Type can be associated with many Events", "An Event can be associated with only 1 Event Type". Taking this approach sets you up for extensibility down the road. Imagine you want to add a new Event Type. You simply create a new event entity and associate it to your Event Type entity.

My suggestion is to think about your object model relative to how you anticipate using the objects in your code (and how you anticipate accessing the objects via queries). That should help drive how you construct it (e.g. if you need a time object then make sure you have that in your object model. If you need an alert object then make sure you have that in your object model). Let the model do the work for you and try not to write a lot of code to assemble the equivalent of an object model within objective-c or start creating objects in code and populating them with data from your data store.

(EDIT: Replace the "event" relationship in the diagram under time, location & speed with "event types")
[image]

Comment: Wizkid, Thank you, that diagram is a huge help. One thing though - EventType would only have 1 type, not all three. So either Time, Location or Speed.

Comment: That's cool. If the Event Types are more than just a name (i.e. a list), then you might want to represent them as objects in your model (I wasn't really sure what you wanted to do). If it's as you stated then sure drop those 3 entities and you should be good. The way I was thinking of this was an Event can be associated to one of 3 very different event types. The Event Type entity would hold the descriptive info for the type while the Time, Location, Speed would hold the details relative to those objects (e.g. Time: Date, Time, time-range, timezone, whatever). Good luck.

Comment: The thing is - I think they're better as objects. The problem is creating a relationship between those three objects and the Event Type object without creating NULL values as only 1 is mandatory, so the other two would be NULL. How can I refer to just 1 object from the Event Type object without having two more NULL pointers?

Comment: The nice thing is you aren't creating null "objects". When you create a new type, you don't instantiate 4 objects in the data store just because they have relationships i.e. pointers. For example, you will only create a new Time object when you have something to store (i.e. not null). You will then associate the Time object to your Event Type and the Event Type to your Event. Within Event Type, following a fetch that yields no location objects, if you check the location relationship pointer, it will be nil. So the "pointer" is nil. There is no "null object" concept in the repository.

Comment: Again, following a "fetch" the relationship pointers to 2 of the objects would be nil. If your Event Types were more uniform, you could avoid the 3 objects. But your description stated they have very different attributes therefore the 3 objects.

Comment: Right, but when it comes to storing the data in a MySQL db, the EventType table will show NULL values for 2 out of the 3 relationships, wouldn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60111/discussion-between-jcrowson-and-wizkid).

Comment: Yes it would. I don't think there is a way around that given your scenario. If you created a single object and jammed everything into it (e.g. just an Event Type entity and kill the other 3 entities) then you will have a bunch of attributes with null values). So you will have to deal with either a null relationship (=2) or a number of null attributes (>2). I prefer the first because at least you have more flexibility with your queries.